# Date Conversion Issues ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date-conversion

this is going to be a totally newb question but my google-fu isn't landing me anything timely so I figured I would ask you

Trying to do this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSADM.PS_ADM_APPL_PROG
WHERE SCC_ROW_ADD_DTTM>=CAST(TO_CHAR(COALESCE('11-30-2019', '11-30-2019')) AS TIMESTAMP) 
OR SCC_ROW_UPD_DTTM>CAST(TO_CHAR(COALESCE('11-30-2020', '11-30-2020')) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

But the predicate column is formatted as such:

```
04-OCT-12 06.21.14.553375000 AM
```

I'm guessing my TO_CHAR and CAST isn't sufficient due to the error:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

Anyone happen to know off the top of their head how to get past this?

Comment: Why `COALESCE('11-30-2019', '11-30-2019')` instead of just `'11-30-2019'`?

Comment: Well im going to be using variables inside of SSIS, but I need to get the query done correctly first. Unrelated but I guess it looks odd at first lol

Comment: TO_TIMESTAMP with an explicit format mask is what you want. TO_CHAR on a string isn't going to do anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DATE` constant:

```
WHERE SCC_ROW_ADD_DTTM >= DATE '2019-11-30' OR
      SCC_ROW_UPD_DTTM > DATE '2019-11-30'
```

You don't have a time component, so a `date` literal seems sufficient.

If you have variables, you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
WHERE SCC_ROW_ADD_DTTM >= COALESCE(:datevar, DATE '2019-11-30') OR
      SCC_ROW_UPD_DTTM > COALESCE(:datevar, DATE '2019-11-30')
```